# HTTP GET request with proper content-type is not hitting the expected service method

Tags: web-services, rest, get, jersey, conflict

I have 2 restful service method getCustomerJson and getCustomerXML in a class CustomerResource where i am using jersey API for Restful Webservices. All the parameters of the 2 methods are same except one produces xml and other produces json.

When i am using the a HTTP GET request with header Content-Type="application/json" it always invokes the getCustomerXML method which returns xml.

Can someone explain me how jersey works in this kind of situation ?

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import domain.Customer;

@Path("/customers")
public class CustomerResource {
    private static Map<Integer, Customer> customerDB = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Customer>();
    private static AtomicInteger idCounter = new AtomicInteger();

    // Constructor
    public CustomerResource() {
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello Kundan !!!";
    }



    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    @Produces("application/xml")
    public Customer getCustomerXML(@PathParam("id") int id, @Context HttpHeaders header) {
        final Customer customer = customerDB.get(id);
        List<String> contentList = header.getRequestHeader("Content-Type");
        List<String> languageList = header.getRequestHeader("Accept-Language");
        List<String> compressionFormatList = header.getRequestHeader("Content-Type");
        if (customer == null) {
            throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        return customer;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Customer getCustomerJson(@PathParam("id") int id) {
        final Customer customer = customerDB.get(id);
        if (customer == null) {
            throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        return customer;
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes("application/xml")
    public Response createCustomer(Customer customer) {
        customer.setId(idCounter.incrementAndGet());
        customerDB.put(customer.getId(), customer);
        System.out.println("Created customer " + customer.getId());
        return Response.created(URI.create("/customers/" + customer.getId())).build();

    }

    @PUT
    @Path("{id}")
    @Consumes("application/xml")
    public void updateCustomer(@PathParam("id") int id, Customer customer) {
        Customer current = customerDB.get(id);
        if (current == null)
            throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND);

        current.setFirstName(customer.getFirstName());
        current.setLastName(customer.getLastName());
        current.setStreet(customer.getStreet());
        current.setCity(customer.getCity());
        current.setState(customer.getState());
        current.setZip(customer.getZip());
        current.setCountry(customer.getCountry());

    }

    @DELETE
    @Path("{id}")
    public void deleteCustomer(@PathParam("id") int id) {
        customerDB.remove(id);
        System.out.println("Deleted !");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Accept: application/json`. `Accept` tells the server what type you want back. `Content-Type` if for the type of data you are *sending* to the server, like with a POST request.

Comment: And before you even ask this question, if you receive an error message about no MessageBodyWriter for type application/json, it means you need a JSON provider. You need to search around for one. That's kind of off-topic for this question. If you are not getting this error, and everything is working, then just forget this comment :-)